# Use two keys for accessing 3rd level

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, keyboard-layout

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04.

I want to use BOTH AltGr and the left Win key to access the third level (because it makes typing LaTeX code easier). On xfce4-keyboard-settings the Left Win key is assigned to the Compose key but that doesn't do the trick. What I want is, for example, to access the backslach (), which is on the 3rd level of key 20 and whose 1st level is ' (apostrophe), by pressing either AltGr+' AND LWin+'. I know this was possible on Gnome 2 under the Layout options but I can't seem to make it work on XFCE.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terminal command to do what I want is

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 133 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

so I just added this command to the XFCE Startup. There should be a more elegant way through a setup file in the Home directory though, although adding a .xmodmap file didn't work.

In this case 133 is the Left Win key; you can get this by running xev on a terminal, pressing the key for which you want the code and it will be printed on terminal. Hope this helps some other people.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

- Open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing
- Set `XKBOPTIONS="lv3:lwin_switch"`
- Reboot